# How to upgrade to popperjs/core via package.json: name can only contain URL-friendly characters?

Tags: package.json, cookiecutter-django, popperjs

So, I wanted to upgrade my package.json stack due to a harmless deprecation warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.14.3: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
```

Turns out popper.js is deprecated and replaced by popperjs/core. But there's a slash in that name.

```
npm ERR! Invalid package name "popperjs/core": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

Looks like the author of this new repo decided to have a / in the name which breaks my package.json. Any ideas how to approach this?

In my package.json, I call list "popperjs/core": "2.5.2" which prompts the URL-unfriendly naming.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently, it just needs an @ in front:
"@popperjs/core": "2.5.2"